How to convert excel to pdf in Odoo 17
In odoo 17, there is a function to download an excel file. This function will call a function to read and write data to my excel file. Initially, I have an excel file and I will read and write data to that file later. Then I will save the file into a binary field and when I press the button it will download the file. Now I want to convert from excel to pdf before downloading, and download a pdf file. Can Odoo do that instead? I have to code the xml report to create a pdf file. The reason I want to convert it is because when customizing the pdf, I have difficulty aligning the column cells with Excel? Hope someone can help me?
 def export_payslip(self):
        this = self[0]
        out = self.create_xlsx_file()
        filename = 'phieu_luong.xlsx'
        this.export_filename = filename
        this.write({'data': out, 'export_filename': filename})
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_url',
            'name': 'report',
            'url': '/web/content/hr.payslip/%s/data/%s?download=true' % (
                self.id, self.export_filename),
        }
  


Not sure about what you want to do...Could u write clearly the steps (1,2,3...) of your workflow... do you want to store your data in an odoo model ? in that case, it would be easier to export your data to pdf

b1; Create a binary data field, this is the field that will contain the excel file data, and the export_filename field is just the name of the excel file

b2: there is a function create_xlsx_file() to get data, this function creates a list containing data and then fills in the columns in the excel file. Here I have an excel file in the static/report/ folder. xlsx, t reads and writes that file and writes data to it

b3: t has a file download button, it's called export_payslip which calls my other function, essentially I just read and write data into an excel file then assign that file to the data field and then I download that file. , but now I want to convert to pdf before downloading, hope you can help me find a solution?
